# How do I create a custom view in a custom table view cell?

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

I am trying to create a custom checkbox inside of a custom table view cell.

I have a custom table view cell:

```
class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
   weak var delegate: CellDelegateT?
   @IBOutlet var customCheckbox: VKCheckbox!
}
```

Here's the code to load my tableView:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TransactionsTableViewCell
    let customCheckbox = cell.customCheckbox!
    customCheckbox.line = .thin
    customCheckbox.bgColor = UIColor.white
    customCheckbox.color = UIColor.black
    customCheckbox.borderColor = UIColor.black
    customCheckbox.borderWidth = 2
    customCheckbox.cornerRadius = customCheckbox.frame.height / 2
}
```

Where do I need to place the code that constructs the checkbox? Is the `cellForRowAt` not the correct place?

When I use the code outside of my table cell, it works fine. That's why I think I am placing the checkbox creation code in the wrong place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to you question is **"Yes, you should put checkbox settings to another place. Particularly I would suggest you to move it to `CustomTableViewCell` class"**

There is an opinion, that good Object-oriented software design is based on [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) principles.

**SOLID** is an acronym. And **S** stands for [Single responsibility principle.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). Simply saying - one class should be responsible for one thing and this responsibility should be encapsulated by the class.

In your case `ViewController` takes responsibility for the `Cell`s subview layouting and adjustments. Which breaks at least ~**S**~ in SOLID

**P.S.** To be honest I am a bit afraid to write this answer, because of often arguments about good software design.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking it's recommend that you don't put the code that constructs your checkbox in `cellForRowAt`, as @fewlinesofcode has perfectly explained. Below are two other alternatives to answer your question that I would personally recommend. Hope this helps...

**Option 1:**

```
class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var customCheckbox: VKCheckbox!

    func checkBoxControl() {
        customCheckbox.line = .thin
        customCheckbox.bgColor = UIColor.white
        customCheckbox.color = UIColor.black
        customCheckbox.borderColor = UIColor.black
        customCheckbox.borderWidth = 2
        customCheckbox.cornerRadius = customCheckbox.frame.height / 2
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? TransactionsTableViewCell else { return UITableViewCell() }
    cell.checkBoxControl()
    return cell
}
```

**Option 2:**

```
class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var customCheckbox: VKCheckbox!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        customCheckbox.line = .thin
        customCheckbox.bgColor = UIColor.white
        customCheckbox.color = UIColor.black
        customCheckbox.borderColor = UIColor.black
        customCheckbox.borderWidth = 2
        customCheckbox.cornerRadius = customCheckbox.frame.height / 2
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? TransactionsTableViewCell else { return UITableViewCell() }
    return cell
}
```